# sqlite selection returns no results

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I have this table:

[image]

and I try to select `phone = 9` and `isBlocked = 1`

`SQLiteDirectCursorDriver: SELECT KEY_ID FROM BLOCKED_PHONES_TABLE WHERE KEY_PHONE = ? AND KEY_IS_BLOCKED = ?`

code:

```
    Cursor cursor = this.getReadableDatabase().query(
            BLOCKED_PHONES_TABLE,
            new String[] { KEY_ID  }, KEY_PHONE+" = ? AND "+KEY_IS_BLOCKED+" = ?",
            new String[] { phone, "1" }, null, null, null);

      while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
        result = new Phone();
        result.id = (cursor.getInt(0));
        result.phone = phone;
        result.isBlocked = true;
    }
    return result;
}
```

but I get empty results set.

what do i need to fix?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking for rows whose KEY_IS_BLOCKED column contains the string `1`.

Apparently, you do not have any rows where this value is such a string.

The Android database API supports only string values as parameters here.
Just insert the number directly into the SQL query:

```
Cursor cursor = this.getReadableDatabase().query(
        BLOCKED_PHONES_TABLE,
        new String[] { KEY_ID },
        KEY_PHONE + " = ? AND " + KEY_IS_BLOCKED + " = 1" + ,
        new String[] { phone },
        null, null, null);
```

Comment: i define `KEY_IS_BLOCKED` as Bit type. So in that case I should use your syntax?

Comment: SQLite has no bit type.

Comment: so how come this didn't fail for syntax error? `CREATE TABLE BLOCKED_PHONES_TABLE ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, KEY_PHONE TEXT UNIQUE,KEY_IS_BLOCKED BIT )`

Comment: i saw this. but again how come it doesn't fall in runtime execution?

Comment: According to the rules in section 2.1, `BIT` results in NUMERIC affinity. It does not make any difference whether you use `BIT` or `FLUFFY BUNNIES`.

Comment: Column affinity does not prevent you from storing other types in the column. If there is an integer value in the column, you can read it with `getInt()`.

Answer (score -2):

Replace :

```
new String[] { phone, "1" }, null, null, null);
```

by

```
new String[] { String.valueOf(phone), "1" }, null, null, null);
```

And replace :

```
while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
    result = new Phone();
    result.id = (cursor.getInt(0));
    result.phone = phone;
    result.isBlocked = true;
}
```

by :

```
if(cursor!=null){
    cursor.moveToFirst()
    result = new Phone();
    result.id = (cursor.getInt(0));
    //TODO : print ID_KEY to check result...
}
```